# SQL - How To Use "CROSS APPLY" In Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I have two tables (**carousels** and **carousel_images**)

**carousels** table

| id | small_img_1 | small_img_2 | large_img_1 | large_img_2 | img_cta_1 | img_cta_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | cta_1 | cta_2 |
| 76 | 201 | 202 | 203 | 204 | xxx | xxx |

**carousel_images** table

| id | url | alt_tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | http_101 | text_101 |
| 102 | http_102 | text_102 |
| 103 | http_103 | text_103 |
| 104 | http_104 | text_104 |

**Expected Result** I would like to return the following results. Which selects all the images required to build a carousel where `carousel.id == 1`.

| img_id | small_img | small_img_url | small_img_alt | large_img | large_img_url | large_img_alt | img_cta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | http_101 | text_101 | 103 | http_103 | text_103 | cta_1 |
| 2 | 102 | http_102 | text_102 | 104 | http_104 | text_104 | cta_2 |

**Issue** - This is how far I've gone. I can't get results for `large_img_1` and `large_img_2` induced in my results.

| img_id | small_img | small_img_url | small_img_alt | img_cta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | http_101 | text_101 | cta_1 |
| 2 | 102 | http_102 | text_102 | cta_2 |

This is my query so far.

```
SELECT
    [img_id],
    [small_img],
    [large_img] [img_cta],
    [carousel_images].[url] AS 'small_img_url',
    [carousel_images].[alt_tag] AS 'small_img_alt'
FROM
    [dbo].[carousels] CROSS APPLY(

        VALUES
            (1, [small_img_1], [img_cta_1]),
            (2, [small_img_2], [img_cta_2])
    ) V(img_id, small_img, img_cta)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [carousel_images] ON [small_img] = [carousel_images].id
WHERE
    [carousel_images] = 75;
```

Can someone please help? I've been stuck for days.

Also its a legacy system, so that's why the table structure is the way it is. I can't change it unfortunately :(

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: @Squirrel I've added a heading called "Expected Result" for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

You need to add `large_img` to the `CROSS APPLY`.
And join to `carousel_images` twice. Once for the `small_img` and once for the `large_img`

```
SELECT
    v.[img_id],
    v.[small_img],
    s.[url]       AS small_img_url,
    s.[alt_tag]   AS small_img_alt,
    v.[large_img],
    l.[url]       AS large_img_url,
    l.[alt_tag]   AS large_img_alt,
    v.[img_cta]
FROM
    [dbo].[carousels] c
    CROSS APPLY
    (    
        VALUES
            (1, [small_img_1], [large_img_1], [img_cta_1]),
            (2, [small_img_2], [large_img_2], [img_cta_2])
    ) v (img_id, small_img, large_img, img_cta)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[carousel_images] s ON v.[small_img] = s.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[carousel_images] l ON v.[large_img] = l.id
```

Comment: Thanks very much this is great! :) you solved that very quick